# Write files from a jupyter notebook on a remote host to local host

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, save, cluster-computing, local

I am running jupyter on a remote cluster.
How can I write files to my local machine?
I am running python 3.7.1 and jupyter core 4.6.2

Is there something like the following two

```py
numpy.save(localhost:local/path, DATA)
```

Or

```py
pyplot.savefig(localhost:local/path)
```

Comment: I don't know of a native python way, but you can use `scp` if both your local and remote computer run unix systems to copy files between the two.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to include it in the notebooks workflow.
I will give the `!scp` in python a try

Comment: You may still use `Popen` to run shell commands in python. In Jupyter you may run shell commands by adding an `!`, like `!ls` will run ls for you from a notbook cell.